# Responsive Bootstrap Websites and IOS, is there a fix for this?

Tags: ios, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm currently studying how to build responsive websites, and thanks to the community here i've overcome many of my stumbling areas.

However I'm yet again a little perplexed.
I've spend a lot of hours trying different suggestions on how to ensure a bootstrap website is responsive on an IOS devices.

I have yet to find an answer that works for me. 
If I go to my site at dev.blupace.com with an iPhone 5, the background image is huge and the site takes a long time to load.

I've seen numerous threads on this issue, yet I'm a little surprised there isn't a working solution (or at least one I can find with my limited knowledge).

So I'm hoping that some of the more experienced web developers out there can share a good working  solution.

Kindest of regards,

Comment: You are downloading an image https://dev.blupace.com/img/splash/IMG_1185.JPG which is almost 600Kb big and as far as I can see, it's not used.

Comment: Those are just test images I threw onto the site while doing some stress testing work.. the real issue is the background sizing...  Thanks for the heads up on the images though, i did forget to remove them... :-)